# C# Problem trimming line breaks within strings

Tags: c#, string, trim

I have a string that is populated from an Xceed datagrid, as such:

```
study = row.Cells["STUDY_NAME"].Value.ToString().TrimEnd  (Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());
```

However, when I pass the study string into another part of the program, it throws an error as the string is still showing as :  "PI3K1003\n  "

I have also tried:

```
TrimEnd('\r', '\n');
```

Anybody any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
TrimEnd('\r', '\n');
```

isn't working because you have a space at the end of that string, use

```
TrimEnd('\r', '\n', ' ');
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem in that string is that you do not have a `\n` at the end. You have a `' '` (blank) at the end, and therefore `\n` does not get trimmed.

So I would try `TrimEnd( ' ', '\n', '\r' );`

Answer (score 0):

Use replace instead of TrimEnd, in this case you never run into a 'space problem' problem  ;)

```
 string val = @"PI3K1003\n";
 val = val.Replace(@"\n", String.Empty).Replace(@"\r", String.Empty);
```

But TrimEnd is always solution:

```
TrimEnd('\r', '\n', ' ')
```

Comment: The problem is that this will remove all occurences, even if not at the end of the string, which is possibly not the OP's intent.

Comment: Mb you right, but it just a suggestion. And only @Darren know what he need ;)